# Failing to reference CSV variables

Tags: jmeter

I've put connection configuration into a csv data set so we can load a different configuration on different environments.

I've put the `CSV Data Set Config` as the first element under my test plan, with shared mode for all threads.

[image]

I've added the `Debug Sampler` to see if the content of the csv is parsed correctly and I'm seeing it ok. Even though, as u can see in the screenshot, is failing to resolve the variables when they are used?
I've also tried to put manually the `Variable Names` but I get the same response.

Answer (score 0):

0. You need to show your CSV file (at least first 2 lines) and [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) output in order to get comprehensive help
1. Can it be a typo like the variable is `${CONTEXT_FACTORY}` and you're having it as `${CONTEX_FACTORY}`?
2. If your CSV file have header row with the variable names - set "Ignore first line" to `False`, otherwise you need to provide the variable names, one per "column"

On a one-liner like `some context factory` the following setup should work:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Debug out: https://i.ibb.co/tLSBGwZ/debug.png Sampler: https://i.ibb.co/7Ryc6mq/sampler.png